# Morph one object into another and then use same morph on another object to change it into a different shape

Tags: mesh, particles, transforms, shape-keys, shrinkwrap

I know morphing between shapes has been discussed in other posts, however, I have a particular set of requirements that I'm not able to address based on the information I have found elsewhere and personal experimentation.

I want to morph between two objects and then use that exact same morph/transformation on a separate object to transform it into another shape. For instance if we used transformation x on a cube to transform it into a circle then when we apply transformation x to another object it will become more circular.

Ive tried using shapekeys, shrinkwrap, and particle physics but they all have drawbacks. When I use particle physics I don't believe I can use the same transformation on other objects and while with shape keys I may be able to do so, I'm not able to transform complex objects into others adequately due to differences in the # of vertices. Trying to create objects with equal #s of vertices (subdivision/decimate modifiers) didn't quite work out either (that may not help anyway). If anybody has any ideas for doing this with the requirements stated, even using something other than blender, please let me know.

Comment: Morph is a really broad term, so maybe clarify the sort of morph you're after, and what is not working with the methods you've listed?  

Shapekeys is very literal and granular (take this sequence of vertices, move them this far in this direction,) and particles & shrinkwrap are more macro-level morphs.  Any one of these closer to what you're after?

Comment: B 2.8 has an interesting built-in morphing addon, demo here:  https://youtu.be/Ly64vezt0Go

Comment: Sure, so for instance if I have a blend object that's a truck I want to be able to turn it into a plane or any other type of object I may have. The other part of my requirement is that the mapping between truck and plane needs to be saved so that it can be applied to another object e.g. a football. You can save a mapping like that I believe using shape keys but the challenges Im running into are that the objects have different numbers of vertices which can make morphing between objects an issue when using shapekeys/shrinkwrap. I could use particles but cant save the mapping as far as I know

Comment: That add on looks very interesting. I wasn't aware of that one so thank you for sharing it. Now using that add on could I morph between two objects I've appended to a scene that have different numbers of vertices like in the example I desribed above and then save that morph/mapping for reuse (e.g. like a shape key)?

Comment: So you want truck:plane to map to football:xxx.   I'm not sure what blender would do with that, but interesting idea!  

To use that addin I suggested, you'll need to convert original objects into curves first, then I think you can feed both shapes to the addon.  I haven't tried it, but I do believe you can copy shapekeys between objects, but you still might need to get the vertex count to be equal. 

I'm not really sure how shapekeys are stored, however, so it might be by vertex order and you might just get noise if you feed a (truck:plane) shapekey to a football mesh.  

Good luck!

Comment: Yup exactly. Oh ok interesting. Yeah most of my objects are composed mostly of meshes so I guess I can convert them into curves first and then feed them into the add on. Yeah unfortunately that's been the big limitation in blender that shapes need to have equal vertices and it's been a challenge to get them to equal. But I will definitely give the addon idea a try. Thank you very much for your assistance. Appreciate it!